# Are the groups $(\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z,+)$ and $(\mathbb Z/13\mathbb Z,\times)$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I know both have the same number of elements so that is not a problem but I am having trouble showing this.  What could be a map I can use to do this?

Comment: Technically, $(\mathbb Z/13\mathbb Z,\times)$ is not a group, but the non-zero elements are a group.

Answer (score 4):

Yes: the group $(\mathbb{Z}_{13}\setminus\{0\},\times)$ is also a cyclic group of order $12$, since it is generated by $2$, which is an element of order $12$. So$$\begin{array}{ccc}(\mathbb Z_{12},+)&\longrightarrow&(\mathbb{Z}_{13}\setminus\{0\},\times)\\n&\mapsto&2^n\end{array}$$is a group isomorphism.

Comment: Okay I'm trying to show it's a bijective homomorphism do you possibly have a map for that?

Comment: Map the generator to the generator.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, if $p$ is prime, then the groups $(\mathbb Z/(p-1)\mathbb Z,+)$ and $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z,\times)$ are isomorphic. However, an explicit isomorphism cannot be given in general, because no one knows how to find primitive roots explicitly. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots) for instance.